# INSERT a row per array object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post

I am in the process of creating a document association tool whereby users can associate documents to a ticket from a pre-existing list of documents.

Thanks to the help of Alberto Ponte I was able to construct the initial radio box system (originally checkbox, changed for obvious reasons) from this question: [Separate out array based on array data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657216/separate-out-array-based-on-array-data)

Now that I have the radio buttons presenting correctly I am trying to get the data inserted into a MySQL with a row for each document.  Following on from this I want to have it look up the table for each object and see if there is an existing entry and update that rather than inset a duplicate entry.

Apologies in advance for the soon to be depreciated code and I will be correcting the code going forward, however that is a much bigger task than I currently have time for.

Also apologies if the code is considered messy.  I'm not fantastic at PHP and not too hot on best practices.  Any quick pointers are always welcome.

Display code:

```
<?php

include "../includes/auth.php";
include "../includes/header.php";

## Security ########################################################

if ($company_id != 1 OR $gid < 7) {

echo'          <div class="pageheader">
                  <div class="holder">
                     <br /><h1>Access Denied <small> Your attempt has been logged</small></h1>
            </div>
         </div>
';
exit();
}

// GET Values ###################################################
$jat_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$div_id = intval($_GET['div_id']);




## Page Start ########################################################



echo '
               <div class="pageheader">
                  <div class="holder">
                     <br /><h1>Clovemead Job Management Platform<small> Welcome...</small></h1>
            </div>
         </div>

<div class="well5" style="width:1000px !important;">
<h3>Create Document Association</h3>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td align=center><p>Here you can associate documents to Jobs and Tasks to.</p> </td>
  </tr>
</table>';

            $order2 = "SELECT * FROM documents";
                $result2 = mysql_query($order2);
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

                $nice_name = $row2['nice_name'];
                $doc_id = $row2['id'];

}


echo '


<h3>Documents</h3>

<table border=1>
  <tr><th>Document Name</th><th>Document Type</th><th>Required</th><th>Optional</th><th>Not Required</th></tr>
';



            $order2 = "SELECT * FROM documents ORDER BY type_id";
                $result2 = mysql_query($order2);
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

                $nice_name = $row2['nice_name'];
                $doc_id = $row2['id'];
                $doc_type_id = $row2['type_id'];

echo '

  <tr>
    <td>'.$nice_name.'</td>';

            $order3 = "SELECT * FROM document_types WHERE id = '$doc_type_id'";
                $result3 = mysql_query($order3);
                while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {

                $type_name = $row3['type_name'];

echo '
    <td>'.$type_name.'</td>
    <form method="post" action="create-doc-assoc-exec.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$doc_id.'" name="doc_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$jat_id.'" name="jat_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="'.$div_id.'" name="div_id">';

                $order4 = "SELECT * FROM document_assoc WHERE doc_id = '$doc_id'";
                $result400 = mysql_query($order4);
                $_results = mysql_fetch_array($result400);
                if (!$_results) {
    echo '
                    <td><input type="radio" name="req0" value="2"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="req0" value="1"></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="req0" value="0" checked ></td>';
                    } else {
                            foreach ($_results as $result400) {
                            $requirement = $_results['requirement'];
                                        }
                    $name = "req".$doc_id;

    echo '
            <input type="hidden" value ="'.$name.'" name="name">
                <td><input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="2" '; if ($requirement == 2) { echo ' checked '; } echo '></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="1" '; if ($requirement == 1) { echo ' checked '; } echo '></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="0" '; if ($requirement < 1) { echo ' checked '; } echo '></td>';


    }

    }

echo '
  </tr>';
}
echo '
</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Create Document Association" class="btn success Large"></form>';


            $order2 = "SELECT * FROM divisions WHERE id = '$div_id'";
                $result2 = mysql_query($order2);
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

                $dbname = $row2['division_dbname'];

            $order3 = "SELECT * FROM $dbname WHERE id = '$jat_id'";
                $result3 = mysql_query($order3);
                while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {

                $type = $row3['type'];
                $type2 = strtolower($type);

echo '

        <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location=&#39;./view-'.$type2.'.php?id='.$jat_id.'&#39;" class="btn primary Large">



';

}}
echo '
</div>';

include "../includes/footer.php";
?>
```

Execute Code:

```
<?php
include "../includes/dbconnect.php";
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$name = stripslashes($name);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);


$doc_id = intval($_POST['doc_id']); 
$jat_id = intval($_POST['jat_id']); 
$div_id = intval($_POST['div_id']); 
$req = intval($_POST[$name]); 
$req_blank = intval($_POST['req0']); 


if ($req_blank == 0) {
$requirement = 0;
} elseif ($req_blank == 1) {
$requirement = 1;
} elseif ($req_blank == 2) {
$requirement = 2;
} elseif ($req == 0) {
$requirement = 0;
} elseif ($req == 1) {
$requirement = 1;
} elseif ($req == 2) {
$requirement = 2;
}


foreach ($doc_id as $doc_id2) {


$order = "INSERT INTO document_assoc (jat_id, dept_id, doc_id, requirement) VALUES ('$jat_id', '$div_id', '$doc_id2', '$requirement')";
$result = mysql_query($order);

            $order1 = "SELECT * FROM divisions WHERE id = '$div_id'";
                $result1 = mysql_query($order1);
                while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

                    $dbname = $row1['division_dbname'];



            $order2 = "SELECT * FROM $dbname WHERE id = '$jat_id'";
                $result2 = mysql_query($order2);
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

                    $type = $row2['type'];
            $type2 = strtolower($type);

if($result){
header("location:view-$type2.php?id=$jat_id&creation=success");
} else {
header("location:view-$type2.php?id=$jat_id&creation=failed");
}
}}

}
?>
```

A few reference points:

```
$doc_id is the ID of each document which is to be passed over as an array for use in a (i believe) foreach insert
$jat_id is the ticket id documents are being associated to
$div_id is the department the ticket is associated
And the radio boxes are to decider the requirement of each document.  To be passed over inline with $doc_id
```

What I have tried:

After a fair bit of searching - finding nothing - rechecking my terminology and searching again I managed to find the suggestion of using `base64_encode(serialize())` on the arrays but I could not get this to work.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thanks njk - covered this in my post though - "Apologies in advance for the soon to be depreciated code and I will be correcting the code going forward, however that is a much bigger task than I currently have time for."

Comment: the display code needs a bit of format and... does that work? I don't think so: you have straight HTML into PHP without any `<?php`(guess some echo are missing). Also please try to format it a bit better, it's very hard to read. Last of all, what result are you getting when executing your code? doing a `print_r` of the variables you get by POST should also help.

Comment: Sorry it is a clip of code - shall update

Comment: When I echo out $doc_id on the execute page I get just the last document id - not Array

Comment: Do you have any code samples for how you would suggest I format my code please - people keep telling me to clean it up - but now really sure what or how to clean up?

Comment: print_r gives same as echo - last doc id

Comment: Ok - I have changed the name of the radios to name="req0['.$doc_id.'] and name="req1['.$doc_id.'] - which gives me Array ( [4] => 2 ) on print_r - I have used the $doc_id so that I can associate it again in the execute page, but not really sure how to get this working

Comment: Changed the way i was doing this and used comma arrays into the database and then php combined arrays rather than SQL arrays which allowed me achieve what I was trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770222/custom-key-comma-array-allocated-to-an-comma-array