# Custom key comma array allocated to an comma array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following arrays:

```
$doc_id = (3,5,4,6)
$requirement2 = (2,0,0,1)
```

I am trying to make `$doc_id` the key element of `$requirement2` using the following code:

```
<?php

include "../includes/auth.php";
include "../includes/header.php";


$jat_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$div_id = intval($_GET['div_id']);


    $order = "SELECT * FROM document_assoc WHERE jat_id = '$jat_id'";
    $result = mysql_query($order);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $doc_id3 = $row['doc_id'];
    $doc_id = explode(",", $doc_id3);

    $requirement = $row['requirement'];
    $requirement2 = explode(",", $requirement);

    foreach ($doc_id as $doc_id4) {
    $requirement3 = array($doc_id4=>$requirement3);

    foreach ($requirement2 as $requirement3) {
    $requirement3 = array($doc_id4=>$requirement3);

    print_r ($requirement3);

    }}
include "../includes/footer.php";

?>
```

However I receive the following on the print_r():

```
Array ( [3] => 2 ) Array ( [3] => 0 ) Array ( [3] => 0 ) Array ( [3] => 1 ) Array ( [5] => 2 ) Array ( [5] => 0 ) Array ( [5] => 0 ) Array ( [5] => 1 ) Array ( [4] => 2 ) Array ( [4] => 0 ) Array ( [4] => 0 ) Array ( [4] => 1 ) Array ( [6] => 2 ) Array ( [6] => 0 ) Array ( [6] => 0 ) Array ( [6] => 1 )
```

Which is the closest I have been so far.  But obviously still wrong.

From what I have read I need it to look like this:

```
Array ( [3] => 2 [5] => 0 [4] => 0 [6] => 1 )
```

So that later on I can call it by `$requirement3[$doc_id]`.  (the $doc_id will be a different variable source when calling it than from setting it within this array key).

If someone could help explain what I am doing wrong with the 2 `foreach` statements I would greatly appreciate the better understanding.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$requirement3 = array_combine($doc_id,$requirement2);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Demo: http://codepad.org/bDhBw2aZ

Comment: Thanks Guys!  My problem was that I did not need foreach at all haha!  Works a treat! Cheers - Will accept in 5 mins when it allows me